# Strange Compiler Error, stating that my iterator is undefined

Tags: c++, scope, compiler-errors, expected-exception

I'm trying to create a template function which will iterate through the map's specified key/value pairs and check to see if there exists any keys specified in the function's parameters.

The implementation looks as follows:

**Code**

```
template < class Key, class Value >
bool CheckMapForExistingEntry( const std::map< Key, Value >& map, const std::string& key )
{
    std::map< Key, Value >::iterator it = map.lower_bound( key );
    bool keyExists = ( it != map.end && !( map.key_comp() ( key, it->first ) ) );
    if ( keyExists )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Yet, for whatever reason, I can't seem to figure out why my code won't compile. I get these errors instead:

```
error: expected ';' before 'it'
error: 'it' was not declared in this scope
```

I've ran into these before, but these usually have been due to mistakes I've made which are easy to spot. What could be going on here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty sure you need a `typename` qualifier:

```
template < class Key, class Value >
bool CheckMapForExistingEntry( const std::map< Key, Value >& map, const std::string& key )
{
    typename std::map< Key, Value >::iterator it = map.lower_bound( key );
    bool keyExists = ( it != map.end && !( map.key_comp() ( key, it->first ) ) );
    if ( keyExists )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

[This article](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html) explains in considerable detail.

Effectively, the compiler knows that there could potentially be a specialization of `std::map< Key, Value >` for certain values of `Key` and `Value` which could contain a `static` variable named `iterator`.  So it needs the `typename` qualifier to assure it that you are actually referring to a type here and not some putative static variable.

Comment: @Holland The code could use a bit more cleanup before it will run. See http://ideone.com/lcsQB

Comment: Good point.  I just addressed the particular error he reported.